# Custimize Error Message for hook "commit-msg" in Egit on Windows

Tags: git, hook, egit, jgit, commit-message

As the title says .. I am trying to set up a commit-msg hook in an eclipse project/git repo. I just added the script into my .git folder and from the command line the hook triggers, and i get my Error message.

```
#!/bin/bash

ISSUE_KEY=`some-regex`
if [ "" ==  "$ISSUE_KEY" ]; then
echo 'Commit rejected - Please edit your commit message'
exit 1;
fi
```

in Eclipse the hook didnt trigger at first, but after i installed Cygwin, it worked. 
The Problem is though, that i just get a default prompt saying

**Commit was aborted by hook - Rejected by "commit-msg" hook**

And not the message from the  "echo output".
Is there a way to customize my Error message for egit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, EGIT is horrible concerning all GIT operation, in general I prefer using some external tool to manage all GIT operations. Git bash or GitExtentions, etc.

But since I have to support other users in Eclipse, I found out the following:
1. Use Eclipse Oxygen so eclipse will at least run the hooks. I found that Luna will not execute them at all on Windows.

AND

2. Install Cygwin, or at least make the "sh.exe" in C:\cygwin\bin folder. Eclipse uses this file to execute the hook
3. Write all the hooks output to some file, e.g. C:\Temp\hooks_log.txt and when it fails check inside that log file

   ```
   {
       ....
       My hook code
       ....
   } |& tee /c/temp/MyHook.log
   ```

The other option is you are more than welcome to fix the EGIT so it will show the log.